# RegExpValidator take in numbers with . with two decimal places

Tags: javascript, validation, qml

I am working on some input validation for QML/javascript using RegExpValidator code below:

```
RegExpValidator { regExp: /^[0-9\.\,]{1,6}$/ }
```

Is there any way to allow user up to 3 numbers before . and then 1 or 2 max after it? 
so that this would work: 10 10.1 10.11 100.1 100.11 10,11
But these wouldn't work: 1000 100.111 and etc

I've tried googling it but didn't mind much.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
^(\d{1,2})([\.|,]\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: No problem.  The solution may need to be modify a little bit if you want to extract parts of the number.  Otherwise, if it is to match, it's good

Comment: You're going to want to remove the pipe in the character class `[\.|,]`, or else it allows for stuff like 23|23.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This is untested. Give it a shot. You can also replace `[0-9]` with `\d`, which is shorthand for digits.

```
RegExpValidator { regExp: /^[0-9]{0,3}([\.\,][0-9]{1,2})?$/ }
```

Comment: Yours did work but some reason it was expecting . or , and would not work without them apart that all good :)

Comment: Ahh yes, that is happening because I didn't quantify the section that is specifying '.' or ','. I will edit this shortly. It will probably look very close to user1168095's answer.